# wordpress user management user specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, user-management

I want create wordpress website into which I want create user management...

That means only registered users with specific role can see restricted pages of my websites and visitors can see only the common pages. Also user can see/edit his/her profiles...

I also want to create login functionality for the same but I think for that plugins are avilable...

Kindly suggests me if any plugin is available for that or how can I develop the code for the same...

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this plugin link, i think most of the requested features is available in this plugin. You can also check a plugin listing from this link - http://www.webdesignlessons.com/7-user-management-plugins-for-wordpress/

Plugin URL - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/

Comment: user access manager seems to be useful in my case but it doesn't has user register/login functionality...

Comment: @mahesh you can add another plugin/widget to provide this functionality..any specific plugin fulfilling all your requirement is hard to get :(